# Extjs form success function doesn't execute even if url returns {"success":true}

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

1. Php Code

   ```
    <?php
      Class semester extends CI_Controller
      {
        public function index()
         {
           echo '{"success":true}';
         }
      }
    ?>
   ```
2. ExtJS Code

   ```
   var form=this.up('form').getForm();
   form.url = 'http://localhost/anju/index.php/semester';
   form.method = 'POST'; 
   form.submit({
         success: function (form, action) {
            alert("Success: " );
        },
        failure: function (form, action) {
            alert("Failure: " );
        }
      });
   ```

I couldn't make a success message so far :( can somebody tell me why it is failing ?

Comment: I really doubt that echo is valid response here. But I am not used to php

Comment: It can be sra. Bijoy, what do you see when you call this url: `http://localhost/anju/index.php/semester`

Comment: it does print exactly {"success":true}

Comment: Sorry, it was completely my fault, when i filled the form it does work how it has to work,